# Matching only leftmost wildcard in the domain name - Python

Tags: python, regex, http, url, dns

I'm trying to write a regex for only the leftmost wildcard in the domain name. So far I have this:

```
import re
    o = urlparse(argv[1])
host_name = o.netloc
context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_METHOD) # Use TLS Method
context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2) # Don't accept SSLv2
context.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
                   callback)
# context.load_verify_locations(ca_file, ca_path)

sock = socket()
ssl_sock = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
ssl_sock.connect((host_name, 443))
ssl_sock.set_connect_state()
ssl_sock.set_tlsext_host_name(host_name)
ssl_sock.do_handshake()

cert = ssl_sock.get_peer_certificate()
common_name = cert.get_subject().commonName.decode()
print "Common Name: ", common_name
print "Cert number: ", cert.get_serial_number()
regex = common_name.replace('.', r'\.').replace('*',r'.*') + '$'
if re.match(regex, host_name):
    print "matches"
else:
    print "invalid"

# output:
Common Name:  *.example.com
Cert number:  63694395280496902491340707875731768741
```

However, the regex is matching not only `*.example.com`, but `*.*.*` or `www.*.com`. Also, `https://wrong.host.example.com/` should not be allowed to match. How can I make sure it only matches the leftmost label?

Comment: What is an example of a correct match?

Comment: *.example.com is a valid correct match

Answer (score 0):

You could use urlparse and split instead of regex.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
.
.
common_name = cert.get_subject().commonName.decode()
domain = urlparse(common_name).netloc
host = domain.split('.',1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
r'(?:^|\s)(\w+\.)?example\.com(?:$|\s)'
```

Full demo:

```
sock = socket()
ssl_sock = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
ssl_sock.connect((host_name, 443))
ssl_sock.set_connect_state()
ssl_sock.set_tlsext_host_name(host_name)
ssl_sock.do_handshake()

cert = ssl_sock.get_peer_certificate()
common_name = cert.get_subject().commonName.decode()
print "Common Name: ", common_name
print "Cert number: ", cert.get_serial_number()

rxString = r'(?:^|\s)(\w+\.)?' + common_name.replace('.', '\.')[3:] + '(?:$|\s)'
regex = re.compile(rxString)

if regex.match(host_name):
    print "matches"
else:
    print "invalid"
```

Input:

```
url                
-------------------
www.example.com    
example.com        
hello.example.com  
foo.bar.example.com
*.*.*              
www.*.com
```

Output:

```
url                  |  result
-------------------  |  -----------
www.example.com      |  matches
example.com          |  matches
hello.example.com    |  matches
foo.bar.example.com  |  invalid
*.*.*                |  invalid
www.*.com            |  invalid
```

Comment: Saleem, how can I build the regex like yours? My current one is `regex = common_name.replace('.', r'\.').replace('*',r'.*') + '$'` so how can I do something similar?

Comment: @philippe it's simple. I think you don't need to replace anymore. simply replace yours `re.match(regex, host_name)` with `p.match(host_name)` provided that you are copying first two lines of my solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in Saleem's answer Regexp is wrong and not compliant with RFC6125[6.4.3].

1. neither 'example.com' nor '.example.com' must not be matched.
2. It's possible to have wildcard like this: f*.example.com.
3. You should not expect any spaces(\s) characters in front of and at the end of string.

I think, the best way is to change '*' character with '[^.]+' (or '[^.]*' - the RFC is not clean should f.example.com match with f*.example.com or not):

```
rxString = '^'+common_name.replace('.','\.').replace('*','[^\.]+')+'$'
```